# In qlikview , Is it possible to keep the script window always open?

Tags: qlikview

During the code development it  would be better if I could reload my code and keep the script window open. At the same time it would have to allow me to change or creat objects on my dashboard. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is `No`

But you can achieve this if you split your script from your app. Have one app that contains the script (and nothing else) and one app that [loads Binary](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Binary.htm) from the first app. This app will contain all objects.

The [binary load](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Binary.htm) grabs the whole data from one app and "paste" it in the current app.

So you can reload the app with the script (and continue working on the app with the objects) and when the script app is ready (and saved) just reload the app with the objects. The app with the objects will reload quite quickly because the binary load will grab the reloaded data